# How to Avoid Multiple parameters with Linq Contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a method that accept List of items and using contains to get the results , the issue here it is mapped to IN functions and generated multiple parameters which is not good in SQL.

Is there any alternative to replace contains to avoid the multiple parameters.

```
 public async Task<List<ItemLink>> GetParentLinks(List<int> itemIds)
    {
        return await _db
            .ItemProducts
            .Where(il => itemIds.Contains(il.ChildItemId))
            .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think multiple parameters is a bad thing?

Comment: So the parent row contains a ChildItemId? So it can only have one child?

Comment: Agree with DavidG; you're fixing something that likely isn't a problem

Comment: Can you show generated SQL?

Comment: If this is EF it does not generate an IN statement with parameters. I think you're using LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?